Why getter in kotlin uses INVOKEVIRTUAL?
So I have a simple class in kotlin and a function that gets a field from that class:
class SomeClass {
    var value = 1
}

fun showValue() {
    val klass = SomeClass()
    println(klass.value)
}

A function bytecode would look like this:
public final static showValue()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    NEW com/korol/kittybot/SomeClass
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL com/korol/kittybot/SomeClass.<init> ()V
    ASTORE 0
   L1
    LINENUMBER 9 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL com/korol/kittybot/SomeClass.getValue ()I
    ISTORE 1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ILOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 10 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE klass Lcom/korol/kittybot/SomeClass; L1 L3 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

For some reason, getter is not static. INVOKEVIRTUAL com/korol/kittybot/SomeClass.getValue. I am interested in why. As far as I understand virtual calls are for functions with several implementations. But here the field is not open and the class is neither abstract nor open. Would appreciate if someone can explain it.
It seems Kotlin does not generate static within the class as a rule. It can only be generated in companions or objects.

This is the same question but for Java.

Your question is about symptoms, despite you know the actual issue. As you said “For some reason, getter is not static” That’s already the answer to the question that you asked. The caller uses INVOKEVIRTUAL instead of INVOKESTATIC because the target method is not static. Apparently, your actual question is “why did the Kotlin compiler decide to use a non-static getter for this property?”. So, if that’s your question, why don’t you ask that question instead asking about the caller’s use of INVOKEVIRTUAL? The caller is irrelevant. The method would be static, even if no caller existed.

@Holger Your response seems tautological: 'The caller uses INVOKEVIRTUAL instead of INVOKESTATIC because the target method is not static.' I understand that the method isn't static, but my question is specifically about why the Kotlin compiler generates the getter as non-static in this scenario (INVOKEVIRTUAL already implies the non-static nature of the function).

That’s precisely what I said, your question seemed to be “specifically about why the Kotlin compiler generates the getter as non-static in this scenario” except that you didn’t ask that specific question. Instead, you asked why the INVOKEVIRTUAL bytecode has been used at the caller and consequently, you got redirected to an entirely unhelpful Q&A, as the question why final methods are invoked via INVOKEVIRTUAL in Java is not even remotely related to your actual question about Kotlin. In other words, the other readers did not even understand what your actual question is.

@Holger well, that seems like a fair point.

I'll start by saying that I am not a Kotlin programmer.

For some reason, getter is not static.

The getter is not static because the property you are getting is not static.  The getter is or could be (in Java terms) final.  However static and final are different things and it is not a static method.
The distinctions (for a method) are:

'static' means there is no target object for the method
'final' means that the method cannot be overridden

Therefore, for your getter example:

There is a target object: the SomeClass instance whose value is to be accessed, so the getter cannot be static (in the Java sense).
The getter could be final (in the Java sense) because SomeClass is not open (in the Kotlin sense).



It seems Kotlin does not generate static within the class as a rule.  It can only be generated in companions or objects.

Well, yea.  The Kotlin compiler is implementing the Kotlin language, and in the Kotlin language you >>express<< the equivalent of a Java static variable as a variable in a companion object declaration.

So what about the JVM bytecodes?

INVOKESTATIC is for invoking static methods.  It doesn't allow for a target object.
INVOKEVIRTUAL is for invoking regular non-static methods.  It expects the target object on the opstack.
INVOKEINTERFACE is for invoking non-static methods defined in an interface rather than the subclass hierarchy.
INVOKESPECIAL is for cases where there is no method dispatching: i.e. constructor calls, class initialization, and final method calls that can be resolved at compile time.
INVOKEDYNAMIC is for (other) special cases where more flexible (runtime) dispatching of method calls is required.

In your example:

The Kotlin compiler could emit either a INVOKEVIRTUAL or a INVOKESPECIAL bytecode to call the getter.  Either will result in the correct getter method being called.  The only difference would be (in theory) performance.

INVOKESTATIC cannot be used here.


In practice, a modern HotSpot optimizer can determine (at runtime) that a method is effectively final, and optimize the hardware call sequence to eliminate any unnecessary dispatching via a virtual method table.  Therefore it doesn't make any difference1 whether INVOKEVIRTUAL or INVOKESPECIAL is emitted by the Kotlin compiler for your example.
1 - This assumes that the code containing the call is run often enough to trigger optimization.
